# Disable Ajax.BeginForm if user input does not match the specified conditions

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**Client side:**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddClusion", clusionOptions))
{
    @Html.TextArea("clusionValue", new { onkeyup = "SyncContents(); return false;" })
    <input type="submit" value="Add" onclick="ValidateInput(); ClearDirtyFlag(['clusionValue']);" />
}

<script>
    function ValidateInput()
    {
        if (@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Name)) === "CheckII" &&
        $("#clusionType").val() !== "EcuMnemonic" &&
        $("#clusionValue").val().length > 10)
        {
            //do not submit data to the server.
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Server side:**

```
[Transactional]
public JsonResult AddClusion(Guid id, ClusionType clusionType, string clusionValue, bool isInclusion)
{
    var product = NonDiagnosticRepository.Product(id);

    product.AddClusion(new ProductClusion { Type = clusionType, Value = clusionValue, IsInclusion = isInclusion, ProductId = id });

    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

Is it possible to **not submit** the data to server if the user input doesn't match the specified conditions? If it is, then how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using jquery validation (https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/). This works on the client (browser) side. Because the Ajax.BeginForm runs on the Server side it is not possible to disable it in the server side however you can hide the DOM element for "AddClusion" using something like:

```js
document.getElementById('AddClusion').style.display = "none";
```